# Is it possible to get urns of models which are translated as references via zip translation?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

When I upload and translate a zip-file with one rootFile and some models which act as references to Autodesk-Forge, I could only find one model-urn afterwards. Are all models uploaded separately under the hood and do you have the possibilty to get the urns of each model?

One usecase would be to open any other model from the package than the predefined root, to get to view the 2D-sheets from this model.

Another usecase would be to save data in relation to elements/referenced models with their dbId/guid and urn.

I was expecting to get each models urns by selecting parts from different models and running `this.viewer.getAggregateSelection().lastItem.model` as it would do the trick if I would've translated them separately and aggregated the view.  But this way there's just one urn for all elements.

I also tried inspecting the buckets and objects via the awesome "Autdesk Forge Tools" extension for VSCode, but couldn't get any deeper than the .zip file as an object in the bucket.

Is the only possibility to upload/translate the same .zip-package for every model i want to open with a new defined rootFilename again? Is this still the only possibility as stated in an answer from 2016? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38720162/19956654)

Appreciate any help with this one, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, one ZIP will have one URN only. So, you will need to have the ZIP uploaded with different names and request translations with different `rootFilename`s separately.

However, you don't really need to upload the same file several times. Just call [PUT buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectKey/copyto/:newObjectKey](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-copyto-:newObjectKey-PUT/) to duplicate the uploaded ZIP with different names.